# AWS IAM policy simulation "cannot be performed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to debug some S3 IAM role policy issues, and turned to the AWS IAM Policy Simulator.

Unfortunately, the simulator fails as you can see in the image below.

[image: simulation fail]

There's literally no error reporting and nothing online about this.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please share your policy . If you use any tag based condition on your policy then go simulation setting and use tag value then start run .